# Powershell script to install a specific program. Script works but is there a better way to do everything?

Tags: powershell, installation

Okay so the script below is originally made using Batch and i converted it to PS. It works at the moment but is there better way to do this?

First we want to check is operating system 32 or 64 bit so we'll get the right installation path. Then we want to check is there old installation folder or not and if there is, the script should stop.
If there isn't that old installation folder, we'll create one and then import the registry file.
After that, we want to change drive H: to C:\Temp and then we'll install the msi-file. When the msi-file is installed, we want to check the installation path is the "program.exe" in the right place.
If everything is ok, we want to create folder for the GCTI files and then copy all the necessary files.

At the end of the script there's couple more file copying left and then we are done.

At the moment this script is in the same folder as the necessary installation files and when we use this to install the program, we need to copy the folder to the remote computer. I am planning to change this script a bit so that at first it asks on which computer we want to install this and then it copies all the files to the specific remote computer and then runs this script in remote computer.

```
    #Let's check is OS 32 or 64 bit
    $bit = "C:\Windows\syswow64\."
    $isit64bit = Test-Path $bit
    If ($isit64bit -eq $True) {$installpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)"}
        Else {$installpath = "C:\Program Files"}

    #Let's check is there old installation folder
    $Program = $installpath+"\Program\"
    $Programtest = Test-Path $Program


    If ($Programtest -eq $false ) {Write-Host "None found, let's continue the installation"}
Else {Write-Host "Old installation folder found, remove files and try again" Exit}

    # Create ODBC-connection in registry
    Start-Process -FilePath Reg -ArgumentList import, ".\Progserver_ODBC.reg" -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized

    #Let's check if previous action is ok
    $registry = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Progserver\"
    $registrycheck = Test-Path $registry
    If ($registrycheck -eq $True) {Write-Host "Registrychange is ok"}
    Else {Write-Host "Registrychange failed" Exit}

    # Rename Drive "H:" C:\temp
    New-PSDrive -Name "H" -PSProvider 'FileSystem' -Root C:\temp

    # Install the msi
    Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, "Program-4.3.32.msi", /quiet -Wait
    $install = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PathtoProgram.exe"
    $installcheck = Test-Path $install

    If ($installcheck -eq $True) {Write-Host "Installation succeeded"}
    Else {Write-Host "Installation failed." Exit}

    # Create GCTI's
    $GCTI = "$installpath\PathToGCTI\"
    If (Test-Path $GCTI) {Write-Host "GCTI folder already exists"}
    Else {Write-Host "Create GCTI folder"} New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $GCTI -Force

    Copy-Item .\PathtoGCTI\* -Destination $GCTI -Recurse -Force
    Write-Host "Copied GCTI-files"


    # Copy program.ini ja vec.ini
    Write-Host "Copying program.ini ja vec.ini"
    Copy-Item .\PathToProgram.ini $installpath\PathToProgram.ini
    Copy-Item .\PathToVec.ini $installpath\PathToVec.ini

    # Change folder rights for the installation folder
    cacls.exe $installpath\Program /T /E /G "All Users:C"

    # Copy files from version 4.3.26
    Copy-Item .\PathToProgram.exe $installpath\PathToProgram -Force

    # Copy files
    Copy-Item .\PathToFiles\* $installpath\PathToProgram\ -Force -Recurse
    Set-ItemProperty $installpath\PathToProgram\graph\* -Name isreadonly $true

    #Remove PSDrive
    Remove-PSDrive -Name "H"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means exhaustive; just a selection of comments. You might be better submitting this to the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

General rules:

- **always used named parameters in PS functions**
- Your code formatting **is** important (carriage returns, tabbing/spacing, etc.)

e.g.

```
### Don't do this
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp"
### Instead do this
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp"
```

Test if we're running a 64 bit OS and pick the appropriate Program Files folder

```
if ([environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) {
    $installationPath = $env:ProgramFiles
}
else {
    $installationPath = ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
}
```

When joining file paths, use `Join-Path`:

```
### So don't do this
$Program = $installpath+"\Program\"
### Instead do this
$Program = Join-Path -Path $installpath -ChildPath "Program"
```

When mapping your drive; be careful about scoping.
And probably best ensure you clean up after yourself, too! I have fallen foul of this in the past and it was a nightmare to clean up `:-S`

```
try {
    if (Test-Path -Path "H:\") {
        Remove-PSDrive -Name "H"
    }
    New-PSDrive -Name "H" -Root "C:\temp" -PSProvider FileSystem -Scope Script
    ### do your other stuff
catch {
    throw $_.Exception
}
finally {
    if (Test-Path -Path "H:\") {
        Remove-PSDrive -Name "H"
    }
}
```

Note the defensive programming (check if the drive exists already and remove it if it does!).

For bonus points you could pull the mapping code in to a separate function to avoid repetition ([D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Phew... I think that will do for now!

Good work `:-)`